# Is there a way to add an explanation to an answer on careers.stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

So, there are some answers on SO which I like and I'd like to keep them in my careers.stackoverflow profile, but I feel that a short explanation as to *why* I like the answer might be useful. While I admit that this is a very rare corner case, it seems like it could also offer an employer just a hint more context and information (and perhaps more incentive to look at it)

I would suppose that it might be like a comment on SO proper.

Comment: So, you basically want to explain why you choose the solution? Wouldn't this better fit on the answer itself, for all to see (Adding more context)?

Comment: Not necessarily, "This answer examines the difficulties involved in HTTP Authentication when creating a server in MacLisp" might be obvious if the person read the whole question, but it might not be obvious in the first paragraph.

Comment: The other situation I see is, "I really did create an awesome solution to this problem, but because of other issues in the question, the code is hidden at the bottom of the page."

Comment: Or better yet -- an answer says something well, but since the question is left out, it has far less context and substance.

Comment: would be useful to have such a feature. Though there are at least two workarounds (I tried them both:). 1) "soft" - edit the answer so that it passes through with an explanation 2) submit an answer URL not via _SO answers_ but via _articles/blogs_ - that one allows a free-form summary etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion. Our feeling at the moment is that the answer is its own explanation.